# Do entire functions have infinite radius of convergence?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f$ is an entire function, then is the radius of convergence of its Taylor series, centered at any point $z_0$, equal to infinity?

I tend to think that this is true, because the series converges to $f$ at any point. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Basically, the radius of convergence of a complex power series extends until it encounters a pole or essential singularity of the function.  An entire function has no poles or essential singularities.

Comment: See the proof in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. But I had too few characters, so am using filler now.